# .Net application TCP/HTTP connections limit

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, network-programming

I'm developing an application that is making lots of web requests to one service using multiple proxy servers. (.Net 4.5, console app)

The pseudocode:

```
void Main()
{
  System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100, 100);
  ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;
  var proxyList = new[]{proxy1,proxy2... proxy1000};
  var url = "http://example.com";
  //var threadCount = 5; --> Speed increases 
  var threadCount = 30; --> Speed limit
  // var threadCount = 90; ---> Speed doesn't increase
  for(var i = 0;i<threadCount;i++)
  {
    Task.Run(GetJob);
  }
}

void GetJob()
{
  while(true)
  {
    var proxy = RandomProxy(proxyList);
    SendRequest(url,proxy)
  }
}
```

In the beginning speed increases, but then it reaches some limit which looks like the limit of the requests per application. 
I'm able to make about 1000 requests in 30 threads. Then, if I increase the amount of the threads the time of one request also goes up and the speed remains the same. 
At the same time, if I run another instance of this app on the same machine with 30 threads speed doubles. 
Could anybody explain why it works like this?

Comment: How about the ServicePoint? default maximum number of concurrent connections allowed by a ServicePoint object is 2.

Comment: Windows also has its own TCP/IP settings which you should tune. Search for those in Microsoft TechNet.

Comment: @Ivan, did you try asynchronous sockets?